# How to keep same page width after changing resolution scaling from windows appearence settings?

Tags: html, css

I've been coding a web page on a 1920x1080px screen resolution with scaling set to 100% but when I visualised the page on my friend's screen which has the same resolution but 125% scaling, I realized that the page appeared bigger and had an horizontal overflow because the browser window size is not the same with the different scalings it's 1920x965 in 100% and 1536x740 in 125%.. the problem is that everyone uses a scaling that he prefers, so is there any way to make the page look the same, meaning have the same width in whatever scaling set?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
document.body.style.zoom = "100%"
```

However, this may not work for all browsers. You should also note that different browsers handle zooming differently; some zoom only fonts, others zoom fonts and images too. Therefore, you should style your website keeping in mind all possible screen scenarios; unless user-friendliness is not your aim for this one.

Comment: thanks for commenting, well, you kinda gave me a new starting point to search for the solution, I fixed it by using the css mentioned in this website: https://silvawebdesigns.com/how-to-fix-windows-scaling-issues-above-100-for-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed, All I had to do is to set the right zoom level for every device pixel ratio like mentioned in this website:
https://silvawebdesigns.com/how-to-fix-windows-scaling-issues-above-100-for-your-website/

ps: the zoom is better be applied to root not to the elements like in my code example:

```
@media (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
        :root {
            zoom: 1.25;
        }
    }

    @media (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 1.1) {
        :root {
            zoom: 1.1;
        }
    }
```